# reledmac and aligning text with edarrayc

Tags: reledmac

I try to use the edarrayc-feature of reledmac to typeset text combined with brackets. 
The second output is my desired one:
[image]

But I want it to be totally on the left, aligned with the text 'Some Text'. How can I achieve that without fiddling with negativ \hspace ?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart
Some Text.
\pend
\pstart
\begin{edarrayc} 1 & Romeo Montague & \\ 20 & Juliet Capulet & 
\edatright[Lovers]{\}}{1\baselineskip}\hfill
\end{edarrayc}
\pend
\bigskip
\pstart
\begin{edarrayc}\makebox[2em][r]{1} & \makebox[10em][l]{Romeo Montague} & \\\makebox[2em][r]{20} & \makebox[10em][l]{Juliet Capulet} & 
 \edatright[\mbox{Lovers}]{\}}{1\baselineskip}
 \end{edarrayc}
 \pend
 \endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, for now, I don't see. I don't use a lot this feature of reledmac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work this way:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Some Text.
\pend
\pstart
\hspace{-1.55em}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
$\left.\begin{tabular}{l}Romeo Montague \\
Juliet Capulet
\end{tabular}\right\}$ & Lovers \\
\end{tabular}\hfill
\pend         
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

It's not the nicest way possible and I have no clue what it does to \edtexts etc. but for now it suffices my needs.

The negative \hspace is necessary because \noindent doesn't align properly.